# How to pass throught information parent-children React

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a chat with the following structure:

```
<div className='messages-container'>
    <ChatSidebar/>
    <SelectedChat/>
</div>
```

I want to select the corresponding room in the chat sidebar in order to chat with that specific user.

However, for that I'd need the information of that user in the *SelectedUser* component. I've learnt that I can't pass information in between components that are at the same level, so I'd need to pass that information to the parent and that will broadcast to the rest.

How can that be accomplished?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [Lifting State](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html) technique.
In your case, it might look like this:

```
// MainComponent.jsx
const [selectedUser, setSelectedUser] = useState(user)
return (
  <>
  <SelectedUser selectedUser={selectedUser} setSelectedUser={setSelectedUser}/>
  <div className='messages-container'>
      <ChatSidebar/>
      <SelectedChat selectedUser={selectedUser}/>
  </div>
  </>
)
```

Or, if you can't put both components in the same parent component, you can use [Context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#gatsby-focus-wrapper) to access *selectedUser* from components in different locations.

Comment: Thank you so much! I think the context will do. What about redux? Would it be useful in this situation?

Comment: It depends on many factors. Redux (and other store managers) are useful for storing global state such as theme, current user, etc. But if you decide that a selected user is something that can be used throughout the all project, you can move it to redux whenever you want.
So, general advice: use state in the following order: local react state (useState)-> context -> global store (redux etc.) -> browser store (local storage).

Comment: Thank you very much! I'll take your advices into account!

Answer (score 1):

Although this is not recommended but you can define `SelectedUser` in parent component.

```
const [SelectedUser, setSelectedUser] = useState(null);
```

Now, pass `SelectedUser` and `setSelectedUser` like:

```
<ChatSidebar SelectedUser={SelectedUser} setSelectedUser={setSelectedUser}/>
```

In ChatSidebar Component:

```
const ChatSidebar = ({SelectedUser, setSelectedUser}) {
    return(
        <button onClick={ () => setSelectedUser(newID)} />
   )
}
```